# How to exclude virtual host from varnish 3?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to exclude a single virtual host from varnish 3 config

Cache: **[www].domain.tld**

Dont Cache: **host.domain.tld**

```
### default.vcl
backend foo { .host = "domain.tld"; .port = "8880"; }
backend bar { .host = "host.domain.tld"; .port = "8880";}
# ...
if (req.url == "host.domain.tld") { set req.backend = bar; } 
if (req.url == "host.domain.tld") { return(pass); }
if (req.http.Cookie && req.url == "host.domain.tld") { return(pass); }

# ...

### httpd.conf
Listen 8880
<VirtualHost vhost.domain.tld:8880>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo/
    ServerName vhost.doman.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

The request never reaches the virtual host. I guess the problem is that I request on port 80 and the host listens on port 8880.
What I can do to *fix* this?

Answer (score 1):

`req.url` doesn't contain the domain. You want something like this instead:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.host == "host.domain.tld") {
    set req.backend = bar;
    return (pass);
  }
}
```

This will set the backend for any request going to the domain "host.domain.tld" to "bar" and pass directly to the backend (bypassing the cache).